# dotnet core SDK/Runtime on debian in dockers

Tags: docker, debian, .net-core

I am trying to make a dotnet runtime image for our docker clusters. I followed the following tutorial from microsoft.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxdebian

But when I run "dotnet new console -o hwapp"
I get "Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409"

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM "Our registry"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl libunwind8 gettext -y
#Installing DOTNET CORE SDK
ENV DOTNET_VERSION 1.1.1
ENV DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL `https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release/1.1.0/Binaries/$DOTNET_VERSION/dotnet-debian-x64.$DOTNET_VERSION.tar.gz`
RUN curl -SL $DOTNET_DOWNLOAD_URL --output dotnet.tar.gz \
&& mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
&& tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
&& rm dotnet.tar.gz \
&& ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
```

I also tried the link on Microsoft tutorial but I am still getting the same error.
ANy help is appreciated in advance

Comment: You can safely deploy apps, but I wonder why you need the SDK to be deployed via Docker. What's the benefits of that?

Comment: @LexLi If you want to run, for instance, `dotnet new`, then you need the SDK. If all you want to do, on the other hand, is to run .NET Core apps, then all you need is the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Use this URL instead in your `curl` download.

```
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/1.0.1/dotnet-dev-debian-x64.1.0.1.tar.gz
```

### Explanation

Your script successfully installs the command line interface (CLI) but not the software development kit (SDK). Your `dotnet` directory listing probably looks like this but without the `sdk` directory.

```
$ ls /usr/share/dotnet    
dotnet  host  LICENSE.txt  sdk  shared  ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

If you want to run `dotnet new` or any of the other CLI commands, then your `dotnet` directory needs to include the `sdk` directory.

Both the SDK and the Runtime [Linux downloads are listed here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux). There is a download script at the bottom that simplifies the install. The script shows two download links:

For only the shared Runtime:

```
$azure_feed/$azure_channel/Binaries/$specific_version/dotnet-$osname-$normalized_architecture.$specific_version.tar.gz
```

For the SDK:

```
$azure_feed/Sdk/$specific_version/dotnet-dev-$osname-$normalized_architecture.$specific_version.tar.gz
```

The SDK download link is what we need in order to run the `dotnet` commands. Note that Runtime version 1.1.1 is packaged along with SDK version 1.0.1.

Comment: I also needed to update libstdc++6 http://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error

Comment: My directory structure contains the sdk folder. Let me try the link that you mentioned and see if helps.

Comment: Followed the link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/1.0.1/dotnet-dev-debian-x64.1.0.1.tar.gz. Now getting the error "root@8d683b3ff3eb:/# dotnet new console -o hwapp
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500"

Comment: installed libicu52 on debian jessie after downloading the sdk from Shaun's URL and everything started working. Just want to know why its not working by following the Microsoft's URL?

Comment: @wonderwall "Just want to know why its not working by following the Microsoft's URL?" Which URL?

Comment: @wonderwall In that link, the example `curls` down `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=843453`, which is different than the URL that your questions example runs. That is why the way you implemented it does not work. The URL that your question runs is bringing down only the shared runtime not the SDK.

Comment: I first tried with the Microsoft way. Again tried it did not work.